# how to play two animations in the same time in unity 3D

Tags: animation, 3d, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rotate the Earth around the Sun in Unity 3D..

my question: How to rotates the earth around itself and in the same time it rotates around the sun. I can't do more than one animation for one object in Unity3D?

please,help me.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do something like this :

```
public float speed = 1;
void Update() {
   // Slowly rotate the object around its X axis at 1 degree/second.
   transform.Rotate(speed  * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

   // ... at the same time as spinning it relative to the Sun 
  transform.RotateAroud(sun.transform, Vector3.up,  speed * Time.deltaTime)
  }
```

from http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several options in  Unity3D to do this like blending, layering, adding and fading. Have a look at [Unity - Character Animation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Character-Animation.html) and [Unity - Animation Scripting](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Animation%20Scripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can play two animations at the same time by creating multiple layers directly inside the unity animator system.Here a useful step by step guide:
http://gamedevelopertips.com/unity-run-2-animations/